# TagCloud not working on vercel deployment

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, tag-cloud

this works perfectly fine on my local machine but when i deploy to vercel it no longer shows, I've logged the text, container, and TagCloud all are printing the correct response. I've uninstall and reinstalling TagCloud. at this point I am lost and can't seem to figure it out. any help would be appreciated. I am not getting any errors when building or in the console.

```
import TagCloud from "TagCloud";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./textphere.css";

export const text = [
  "HTML",
  "CSS",
  "Tailwind",
  "Javascript",
  "Typescript",
  "NodeJS",
  "React",
  "Next JS",
  "Webpack",
  "Docker",
  "Babel",
  "Kubernetes",
  "ES6",
  "NoSQL",
  "SQL",
  "YAML",
  "SSR",
  "CSR",
  "SSG",
  "Stripe API",
  "REST API",
  "Graph QL",
] as string[];

function TextSphere() {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      const container = document.querySelector(".tagcloud") as any;

      console.log(container);
      console.log(text);
      console.log("TagCloud", TagCloud);

      const options: any = {
        radius: 300,
        maxSpeed: "normal",
        initSpeed: "normal",
        keep: true,
      };

      TagCloud(container, text, options);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-shpere">
        <span className="tagcloud"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TextSphere;
```

````
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

/* container */
.text-shpere {
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgb(250 250 249 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
}

/* textsphere */
.tagcloud {
    display: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

/* Change color of each text in sphere on hover   */
.tagcloud--item {
    color: #f1c400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tagcloud--item:hover {
    color: #ff6347;
}


@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .text-shpere{
        width: 80%;
        height: 70vh;
       
    }
    .tagcloud{
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 1rem;
        letter-spacing: 0.0425em;
        right: 5rem
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px ){
    .text-shpere{
        padding-top: 10%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .tagcloud{
        font-size: 1rem;
        transform: scale(1);
        border-radius: 50%;
        line-height: 100px;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1400px ){

    .tagcloud{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        transform: scale(1.11);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1530px ){

    .tagcloud{
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        transform: scale(1.15);   
        margin-left: 80px;     
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1900px){
    .tagcloud{
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Remove "return" of "useEffect", locally render 2 spheres, but in production only one, that's how it worked for me

```
import TagCloud from "TagCloud";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./textphere.css";

export const text = [
  "HTML",
  "CSS",
  "Tailwind",
  "Javascript",
  "Typescript",
  "NodeJS",
  "React",
  "Next JS",
  "Webpack",
  "Docker",
  "Babel",
  "Kubernetes",
  "ES6",
  "NoSQL",
  "SQL",
  "YAML",
  "SSR",
  "CSR",
  "SSG",
  "Stripe API",
  "REST API",
  "Graph QL",
] as string[];

function TextSphere() {
  useEffect(() => {
      const container = document.querySelector(".tagcloud") as any;

      console.log(container);
      console.log(text);
      console.log("TagCloud", TagCloud);

      const options: any = {
        radius: 300,
        maxSpeed: "normal",
        initSpeed: "normal",
        keep: true,
      };

      TagCloud(container, text, options);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-shpere">
        <span className="tagcloud"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TextSphere;
```